# Errors with historical leap days

Tags: ruby, date

I'm dealing with some historical data with inaccuracies that my team would prefer not to fix due to uncertainty in the original data. One of the problems is with incorrectly recorded dates parsing as invalid:

```
> Date.parse('1876-02-29')
=> Tue, 29 Feb 1876
```

vs.

```
> Date.parse('1877-02-29')
ArgumentError: invalid date
```

Is there any out-of-the-box way of ignoring the invalid date error to get a Date object anyways? Would this probably just cause validations problems in current or future databases? I'm leaning towards just treating dates as integers for this application.

Comment: Are these being parsed, or are they being rejected? What do you want it to return for `-290-99-48` or `9999-99-99`? If you have problems with your data, I find leaving a separate column with the original value as a record of the source data helps a ton.

Comment: They're being rejected. Our dataset is rather small (~6000) and not growing, and we don't have any other error types, so they don't (and won't) contain other error types.

Comment: Another column is a good idea - maybe a corrected value for searching, and a display version with a note about the problem.

Comment: My rule of thumb when doing conversion on data that's of questionable quality is to *always* keep a record of the original. That way you can back-track to the source to find any errors and fix them instead of scratching your head wondering how much of your data got mangled on conversion. You can re-convert at any time if you've got it on hand to repair any systemic problems. A note column like you say is even better if you want to add annotations on how the problem was repaired. OCR data, for example, is notoriously bad and you basically have to hand fix it.

Comment: If you only have 6000 records, why not print out the invalid dates and just correct them one at a  time by hand?  Otherwise you'll spend hours coding around bad records.

Comment: We're unable to change the data because the problems arose from human recording errors (not OCR), and the data is part of the historical record (the lengthly discussions over the ethics of changing any dates would probably rapidly outstrip time lost in coding around them). Likely to proceed with lossless duplication with notes...

Answer (score 0):

Since you have not described what date you want to replace invalid date data with, any date should work (if that was not what you wanted, then it would your fault of not describing the issue completely). Simply doing `Date.new` would create a date object.

```
require "date"

begin
  Date.parse('1877-02-29')
rescue ArgumentError
  Date.new
end
# => #<Date: -4712-01-01 ((0j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Use the string Luke** (or, even better, speak with the client)

Bad data is bad data, can the client's business logic work without good data in that field?

If yes, then don't even expect it to be a real date, code it as a string and throw it to date if/when business logic demands it, but then if it breaks it's the client's data that needs fixing - not your code and the fact that it broke down is actually more like feature than like a bug.

If the client really needs good data then it's up to the client to fix that data somehow, with your help probably.

And the question follows, if some dates are clearly invalid, how many are wrong and just seem valid?

> Only thing scarier than when something doesn't work and it should is when something works and it shouldn't.